# Mypy - creating a wrapper for function with optional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, optional-parameters, mypy

With Mypy is there a practical way how to write a wrapper for a function with optional arguments besides calling all the variants with every optional argument omitted?

Here is an example where I need to call the method in two variants - with and without the `stopindex` argument:

```py
def index_noex(sequence: typing.Sequence, item: typing.Any,
                startindex: int = 0, stopindex: typing.Optional[int] = None
                ) -> int:
    try:
        if stopindex is None:
            index = sequence.index(item, startindex)
        else:
            index = sequence.index(item, startindex, stopindex)
    except ValueError:
        index = -1
    return index
```

Comment: What's the signature for `sequence.index`. Depending on its default you could just call `index = sequence.index(item, startindex, stopindex)` regardless of the value of `stopindex`.

Comment: @SebastianKreft `sequence.index` is the built-in method. Details of the optional argument implementation in this method is not described in the documentation. Without if-else Mypy complains: `Argument 3 to "index" of "Sequence" has incompatible type "Optional[int]"; expected "int"`

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `Sequence` types require an int as the start and stop indices is that the `index` implementation of some sequences (like `list` or `tuple`), explicitly forbid passing the start or end indices as `None`.

Given the semantics of a missing start index is that the search starts at 0, you can specify it as such when calling it, just like you are doing right now.

The missing end index means the search will reach the end of the sequence. And given that the search will look all elements before `stopindex` you need to pass the length of the sequence as a default.

Hence the following code will work:

```
import typing
def index_noex(sequence: Sequence, item: Any,
               startindex: int = 0, stopindex: Optional[int] = None) -> int:
    try:
        if stopindex is None:
            stopindex = len(sequence)
        index = sequence.index(item, startindex, stopindex)
    except ValueError:
        index = -1
    return index
```